# C# Environment.Exit

Tags: c#

When i have 2 threads and call `Environment.exit` afterwards in the main thread,
its takes about 7 seconds before the application had been terminated.

When i only ran 1 of the threads the `Environment.exit` call is executed instantly.

The threads are just as a test for example:

```
Thread testThread1 = new Thread(() => ThreadTestMethod());
testThread1.Start();

Thread testThread2 = new Thread(() => ThreadTestMethod());
testThread2.Start();

public void ThreadTestMethod() 
{ 
     for (int i =0; i < 1000; i++)
     {
           Console.WriteLine("test");
     } 
}
```

Why does this happen ?

Comment: How are you observing this?  Debug build? Release build? Running from VS or the CLI (cmd or powershell)?

Comment: I cannot verify that. Closes instantly, no matter how many threads I create. Are you sure this is *everything* that could cause this? Might be related to something else you're not showing here.

Comment: If i run the application on a Windows 8 environment i don't have the delay. If forgot to say that i am running this example on a Windows Server 2008 Enterprise evironment

Comment: How do u call Environment.exit ??

Comment: I wait for the threads to stop with testThread1.Join() or testThread2.Join();

(So the threads are done BEFORE calling the environment.Exit)

And when i add a breakpoint before and after the Environment.Exit(0) call and i continue it takes 7 seconds before i come to the next breakpoint. 

System.Environment.Exit(0);

(In release or debug mode it takes 7 seconds to exit on a Windows Server 2008 machine)

Comment: You should really post your main() as well.